# First SO chat message in Haskell followup

Tags: haskell, http, stackexchange, chat

I have wrote an application which asks for the user id, and returns a link to the first available chat message:

**Output**

> Enter user id: 
>   322395 
>   Fetching data... 
>   http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/17?m=231895#231895

**Source code**

```
module Main where

import Network.HTTP (simpleHTTP, getRequest, getResponseBody)
import Text.HTML.TagSoup
import Data.List (isInfixOf, isPrefixOf)

type Link   = String
type UserID = String

hostname = "http://chat.stackoverflow.com"

getDivText :: String -> [Tag String] -> String
getDivText m = innerText
             . takeWhile (~/= "</div>")
             . dropWhile (~/= m)

getURLContent :: Link -> IO String
getURLContent lnk = simpleHTTP (getRequest lnk) >>= getResponseBody

getMessages :: UserID -> IO Integer
getMessages uid = do

    contents <- getURLContent $ concat [ hostname
                                       , "/users/"
                                       , uid ]

    let count = getDivText "<div class=user-message-count-xxl>"
              $ (parseTags contents)

    return (read count)

getFirstMessagePage :: UserID -> IO String
getFirstMessagePage uid = searchLast "" . ceiling . (/100)
                      =<< (fmap fromIntegral $ getMessages uid) where

    searchLast body pg = do 

        let lnk = concat [ hostname
                         , "/users/"
                         , uid
                         , "/?tab=recent&pagesize=100&page="
                         , show pg ]

        body' <- getURLContent lnk

        if "monologue" `isInfixOf` body'
            then return body'
            else searchLast body (pg - 1)

getFirstMessage :: UserID -> IO Link
getFirstMessage ui = do

    page <- getFirstMessagePage ui

    let tags = filter step $ parseTags  page
        lnk  = fromAttrib "href" $ last tags

    return $ concat [ hostname, lnk ]

    where step t = isTagOpen t
                 && "/transcript" `isPrefixOf` fromAttrib "href" t 

main :: IO ()
main = do

    putStrLn "Enter user id:"
    uid <- getLine

    putStrLn "Fetching data..."
    lnk <- getFirstMessage uid

    putStrLn lnk
```

I tried to keep the HTTP requests to a minimum.

If the user has removed messages, than there will be a difference between the pages available and the number of messages in the profile.

To solve this, the app recursively lowers the page number till it finds the last message.

Comment: I think my favorite part about this is the example data used. That user is my favorite on SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`body` is unused in `searchLast`.

I don't like explicit recursion as it is used in `searchLast`. `MaybeT` has the correct behavior for what you want.

`ala X` turns a function like `foldMap` into a function like `fold` by applying the newtype constructor `X` to it and unwrapping the result of the resulting function so that it looks like the type wrapped in the newtype has all the instances defined on the newtype.

`alaf X` works the same, except that it turns a function like `foldMap` into a function like `foldMap`, so that further `ala`-functions can be applied.

[Control.Lens.Wrapped (ala)](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.12.3/docs/Control-Lens-Wrapped.html#v:ala)

`Alt` is the newtype wrapper that gives `Alternative`s like `Maybe` a `Monoid` instance, therefore `ala Alt foldMap` would be `asum`, and `alaf Alt foldMap` is something like "`asumMap`", being to `asum` as `foldMap` is to `fold`.

`(ala MaybeT . alaf Alt) foldMap` = `ala MaybeT (alaf Alt foldMap)` = `ala MaybeT asumMap` (except that `asumMap` doesn't exist) takes `[m (Maybe a)]` and combines it into `m (Maybe a)` using `MaybeT`'s `Alternative` instance.

```
getFirstMessagePage :: UserID -> IO String
getFirstMessagePage uid = (ala MaybeT . alaf Alt) foldMap
    . map fetchMonologue
    . reverse . enumFromTo 0 . ceiling . (/100)
    =<< (fmap fromIntegral $ getMessages uid) where

    fetchMonologue :: Int -> IO (Maybe String)
    fetchMonologue pg = do

        let lnk = concat [ hostname
                         , "/users/"
                         , uid
                         , "/?tab=recent&pagesize=100&page="
                         , show pg ]

        body' <- getURLContent lnk

        return $ mfilter (isInfixOf "monologue") $ Just body'
```